# Microsoft Access Query producing duplicate results

Tags: ms-access, duplicates

I have an Access Query i'm using to produce reports based on a form. I'm having an issue with the query where it's producing duplicate records.

After some investigation, I discovered this is because I have a lookup field with multiple potential values in it, and the query is creating a record each time there is a value in this field despite displaying all the values in each one (Which is the intended outcome).

Any idea how I could fix this? I just want it to display one instance of each record in the query results.

I've already tried setting the query to use Unique Values and Unique Records, and Unique Values just causes it to prompt me to enter data for the lookup field when I run the query.

The SQL for the query is:

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Start Date:] DateTime, [Enter End Date:] DateTime;
SELECT DISTINCTROW RA_Generic.ID, RA_Generic.Title, RA_Generic.Description, 
RA_Generic.[Person Carrying Out], RA_Generic.Hazard_1, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_1, RA_Generic.Control_Measures_1, 
RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_1, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_1_After, 
RA_Generic.Hazard_2, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_2, 
RA_Generic.Control_Measures_2, RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_2, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_2_After, RA_Generic.Hazard_3, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_3, RA_Generic.Control_Measures_3, 
RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_3, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_3_After, 
RA_Generic.Hazard_4, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_4, 
RA_Generic.Control_Measures_4, RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_4, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_4_After, RA_Generic.Hazard_5, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_5, RA_Generic.Control_Measures_5, 
RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_5, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_5_After, 
RA_Generic.Hazard_6, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_6, 
RA_Generic.Control_Measures_6, RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_6, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_6_After, RA_Generic.Date_Updated, 
RA_Generic.Type_Of_RA, RA_Generic.Specific, RA_Generic.[Hazard Types]
FROM RA_Generic
GROUP BY RA_Generic.ID, RA_Generic.Title, RA_Generic.Description, 
RA_Generic.[Person Carrying Out], RA_Generic.Hazard_1, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_1, RA_Generic.Control_Measures_1, 
RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_1, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_1_After, 
RA_Generic.Hazard_2, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_2, 
RA_Generic.Control_Measures_2, RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_2, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_2_After, RA_Generic.Hazard_3, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_3, RA_Generic.Control_Measures_3, 
RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_3, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_3_After, 
RA_Generic.Hazard_4, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_4, 
RA_Generic.Control_Measures_4, RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_4, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_4_After, RA_Generic.Hazard_5, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_5, RA_Generic.Control_Measures_5, 
RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_5, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_5_After, 
RA_Generic.Hazard_6, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_6, 
RA_Generic.Control_Measures_6, RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_6, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_6_After, RA_Generic.Date_Updated, 
RA_Generic.Type_Of_RA, RA_Generic.Specific
HAVING (((RA_Generic.Date_Updated) Between [Enter Start Date:] And [Enter 
End Date:]))
ORDER BY RA_Generic.ID DESC;
```

The field that is causing the issues is HazardTypes

Comment: Please share the query

Comment: How would I attach a query to a stackoverflow question?

Comment: You share the SQL

Comment: Found what you wanted, adding it.

Comment: I've attached the SQL the query generated. I'm somewhat familiar with SQL itself, i'm just unsure about how to deal with this specific issue in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd remove both the `GROUP BY` clause, the `DISTINCTROW`, and move the `HAVING` clause to a `WHERE` clause since you're not doing any aggregating.

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Start Date:] DateTime, [Enter End Date:] DateTime;
SELECT RA_Generic.ID, RA_Generic.Title, RA_Generic.Description, 
RA_Generic.[Person Carrying Out], RA_Generic.Hazard_1, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_1, RA_Generic.Control_Measures_1, 
RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_1, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_1_After, 
RA_Generic.Hazard_2, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_2, 
RA_Generic.Control_Measures_2, RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_2, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_2_After, RA_Generic.Hazard_3, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_3, RA_Generic.Control_Measures_3, 
RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_3, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_3_After, 
RA_Generic.Hazard_4, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_4, 
RA_Generic.Control_Measures_4, RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_4, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_4_After, RA_Generic.Hazard_5, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_5, RA_Generic.Control_Measures_5, 
RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_5, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_5_After, 
RA_Generic.Hazard_6, RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_6, 
RA_Generic.Control_Measures_6, RA_Generic.Worst_Possible_Outcome_6, 
RA_Generic.Level_Of_Risk_6_After, RA_Generic.Date_Updated, 
RA_Generic.Type_Of_RA, RA_Generic.Specific, RA_Generic.[Hazard Types]
FROM RA_Generic
WHERE (((RA_Generic.Date_Updated) Between [Enter Start Date:] And [Enter 
End Date:]))
ORDER BY RA_Generic.ID DESC;
```

Comment: Fixed it! Changed the record source of the report after updating the query and it works now.